# ASP.NET MVC 5 [Authorize] attribute is generating login pop-up in browser instead of redirecting to 302 login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-302, authorize-attribute

I've never seen this happen before: I've decorated a controller with an `[Authorize (Roles = "Admin"]`attribute, but instead of sending unregistered/un-signed users to the Login View via 302 redirect, a javascript-generated sign-in prompt appears in the Chrome browser:

[image]

After entering in his or her credentials, the user is then given a 401 error. The suggestions on SO for [setting the `<authentication mode>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421703/asp-net-mvc-5-wrong-redirect-login-page) and [removing the `<FormsAuthenticationModule>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652808/asp-net-mvc-5-web-config-formsauthenticationmodule-or-formsauthentication?lq=1) in Web.Config don't alter this behavior. I have previously created another project using the exact same controllers, reference libraries, etc. and never encountered this undesired behavior.

The big blind spot for me right now is whether there is some sort of OWIN conflict going on. To observe my app's behavior at startup, I created a test variable inside `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` method and set a breakpoint. I observed during debug that this method wasn't being called at all (see full code block below):

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    var t = 2;
                }
            }
        });
```

To provide more clarity here's the decorated controller with the uncooperative `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult BlogPostsAdmin()
    {
        return View(db.BlogPosts.ToList());
    }
```

Here's the AccountController that is supposed to return the Login View:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Any help?

**UPDATE:** I am just going to hack together a custom authorize attribute from now, though this is not desirable for production:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PortfolioSite.Framework
{

    public class SiteAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an intranet (window authentication) app?

Comment: No, just a generic MVC 5 Web App.

Answer (score 0):

The web config should overwrite the IIS express config but in this case it seems it does not. What you can try to do is to turn it off on the IIS level as well.

You can go to this directory \IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config open up this file and set the

```
 <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
```

Comment: It looks like the last sentence in your answer got cut off.

Comment: @Kanapolis sorry, fixed it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Always good to know more about modifying IIS settings. Checked the applicationhost.config and `<windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />` was already set...

Comment: is it happening in all browsers?

Comment: Happens in IE. Don't have Firefox in my environment.

Comment: No dice. After creating a custom [Authorize] attribute, the app started throwing exceptions for other attributes that no one on my team could successfully troubleshoot. My best guess is it has something to do with how some of the code base copied from an older project is interacting with the 4.5.2 framework I'm using. Gonna start my project over in 4.6 and see how that goes...